# How to add data to nested arrays based on recursive schemas in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a recursive schema like this:

```
export const SecretCommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    
})

SecretCommentSchema.add({
    _id: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true, default: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId() },
    ownerId: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId },
    timeAdded: { type: Number, required: true },
    commentLevel: { type: Number, required: true },
    edited: { type: Boolean, required: true, default: false },
    comment: { type: String, required: true, minLength: [1, "Too Short"] },
    replies: [SecretCommentSchema]
});
```

The `SecretCommentSchema` is nested in a container schema:

```
export const ContainerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ownerId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
    timeCreated: { type: Number, required: true },
    data: [ mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed ],
}, {
    timestamps: true
})
```

However, whenever i try to push an item to a nested reply array, I get this error whenever I attempt to push to a replies array 2 levels deep:

```
Error: Could not find path "data.0.replies.0._id" in schema
```

Here's my code:

```
result = await commentsContainerModel.updateOne(
                        {
                          _id: containerId
                        },
                        { $push: { 'data.$[i].replies.$[j].replies': comment } },
                        {
                          arrayFilters: [
                            { 'i._id': commentChainArray[0] },
                            { 'j._id': commentChainArray[1] },
                          ],
                        }
                    );
```

However, I don't get the error when I do something like this:

```
result = await commentsContainerModel.updateOne(
                        {
                            _id: containerId,
                        },
                        { $push: { 'data.$[i].replies': comment } },
                        {
                            arrayFilters: [
                            { 'i._id': commentChainArray[0] }
                            ],
                        }
                    );
```

I strongly believe that this is an internal mongoose error and not an arror on my part. If there's a better way to push to nested arrays based on the _id in each level(for quicker access), I'd really appreciate if you show me.